# jquery nextAll and skip first element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to add a click event on fist child TD for each TR with class “ topRow”  which toggle all next TR rows with class “subRow” skiping the first TR under TR.topRow.

Table example

```html
<table>
    <tr class="topRow">
        <td>text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="otherRow">
        <td colspan="3">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
        <td>text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
        <td>text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="topRow">
        <td>text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="otherRow">
        <td colspan="3">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="topRow">
        <td>text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="otherRow">
        <td colspan="3">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
        <td>text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
        <td>text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
        <td>text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
        <td>text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jquery I have at the moment

```js
$("tr.topRow td:first-child").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().nextUntil('tr:not(tr.subRow):gt(1)').slideToggle();
});
```

Anther thing I tried

```js
$("tr.topRow td:first-child").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().nextUntil('tr:gt(1):not(tr.subRow):gt(1)').slideToggle();
});
```

But I dont get the result required.

Comment: FWIW: I'd restructure the HTML, and wrap the two header lines and the sub rows into tbodies: `<tbody class="topBody"><tr class="topRow">...</tr> <tr class="otherRow">...</tr></tbody> <tbody class="subBody"><tr>...</tr> <tr>...</tr><tbody>` That will tremendousnessly simplify the selector: `$(this).closest("tbody").next("subBody").slideToggle()` - and it's simply better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just throw a [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) in there for the skip (which also simplifies things), like this:

```
$("tr.topRow td:first-child").click(function () {
  $(this).parent().next().nextUntil('tr.topRow').slideToggle();
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Jxrw5/).